# Как реализовать такое скругление?

Tags: html, css

через border-radius проблематично сделать точь в точь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 50%/10%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: А можете сказать, как вы что-то увидели на белом скриншоте?

Comment: @OliverPatterson всё прекрасно видно на скриншоте.. цвет фигуры отличается

Comment: У меня белый скриншот)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, у фронтов IPS матрица, всё видно нормально)

Comment: У меня три монитора с IPS и не на одном я не вижу что либо) UPD: Окееей, на всех видно, если уже знать куда смотреть!) Интересный тест для мониторов получился :D

Comment: liquid retina всё отлично видно) на ноуте с ips хуже, но тоже видно

Answer (score 3):

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: aqua;
  clip-path: ellipse(90% 45%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>border</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Как вариант, что-то подобное можно реализовать и при помощи clip-path.